# How to make a dynamic/recursive function from several xarray DataArrays

Tags: python, dynamic, python-xarray

### The Problem

I want to calculate a DataArray from another two time-series calculation. The desired output is a projection where the first years are defined in another dataarray and then after a given year, the projection depends on two things: another variable and the value calculated (or given) in previous years.

### Excel's example to get the idea

With fewer dimensions, it would be straightforward in Excel. In this example the calculation is the value of the previous year plus the "other variable"

[image]

### Example data

```
import xarray as xr
given_projection = xr.DataArray.from_dict({'dims': ('energia_vehiculo', 'escenarios', 'ano'), 'attrs': {}, 'data': [[[0, 52.24501200000003, 54.334812480000025, 56.48730697440003], [0, 62.24937600000011, 64.73935104000013, 67.30402533120008]], [[299.695, 302.81542434, 305.9407876536, 309.070039330008], [299.695, 302.26518432, 304.8182980128, 307.35263017958397]]], 'coords': {'escenarios': {'dims': ('escenarios',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': ['Tendencial', 'Aspiracional']}, 'ano': {'dims': ('ano',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023]}, 'tipo_vehiculo': {'dims': (), 'attrs': {}, 'data': 'Buses'}, 'energia_vehiculo': {'dims': ('energia_vehiculo',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': ['BEV', 'Convencional']}}, 'name': 'Nuevos 2020-2028'})
da_forcalculation = xr.DataArray.from_dict({'dims': ('escenarios', 'energia_vehiculo', 'ano'), 'attrs': {}, 'data': [[[5449.0, 5505.734988, 5562.559775520001, 5619.4552605456, 5676.401541062016, 5733.37789069487, 5790.362733696614, 5847.33361926215, 5904.267195156828], [0.0, 52.24501200000003, 106.57982448000006, 163.06713145440008, 221.77129877798416, 282.75840594192977, 346.09628887292206, 411.8545837587772, 480.1047719245175]], [[5449.0, 5495.730624, 5542.15087296, 5588.229639628799, 5633.934696615167, 5679.232664025139, 5724.088976252862, 5768.467847904085, 5812.332238830856], [0.0, 62.24937600000011, 126.98872704000024, 194.29275237120032, 264.23814322483247, 336.90363261166146, 412.3700463166736, 490.7203551168416, 572.0397282504896]]], 'coords': {'tipo_vehiculo': {'dims': (), 'attrs': {}, 'data': 'Buses'}, 'ano': {'dims': ('ano',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': [2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028]}, 'energia_vehiculo': {'dims': ('energia_vehiculo',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': ['Convencional', 'BEV']}, 'escenarios': {'dims': ('escenarios',), 'attrs': {}, 'data': ['Tendencial', 'Aspiracional']}}, 'name': 'Parque'})
```

### First attempt

```
ds=da_forcalculation*0

for t in range(2020,2028):
    if t<=2023:
        ds=ds.drop_sel(ano=t)
        ds=xr.concat([ds,given_projection.sel(ano=t)], "ano")
    else:
        ds=ds.sortby('ano')
        v=da_forcalculation.sel(ano=t)+ds.shift(ano=3).sel(ano=t)
        ds=ds.drop_sel(ano=t)
        ds=xr.concat([ds,v], "ano")
ds
```

This attempt kind of works, but I hope there is a better or cleaner way to do it.

(If someone is familiar with Lumina Analytica it would be like Dynamic function.)

### UPDATE

### Second attempt (not working)

Based on the comments of @Michael Delgado I structured a better way to do it with  `loc` assignment.

```
da_final=da_forcalculation*0

for t in range(2020,2028):
    if t<=2023:
        da_final.loc[{"ano":t}]=given_projection.loc[{"ano":t}]
    else:
        da_final=da_final.sortby('ano')
        da_final.loc[{"ano":t}] = da_forcalculation.loc[{"ano":t}]+da_final.shift(ano=3).loc[{"ano":t}]
```

It gets the error `IndexError: dimension coordinate 'energia_vehiculo' conflicts between indexed and indexing objects` so I supposed I need some kind of reindexing with maybe [xr.DataArray.reindex](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.reindex.html) but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: could you do this with [`xr.DataArray.cumsum`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.DataArray.cumsum.html)? generally any array operations like this will perform much better than trying to loop through individual elements. Other than that I'd say that you should avoid as much as possible resizing/concatenating arrays inside a for loop like this. better to store things in a list or dictionary within the loop and then concatenate once at the end. Also note you can assign array values with loc, e.g. `ds.loc[{'time': t}] = val`

Comment: I'm looking for a more flexible cumulative function than cumsum, because I want to make a calculated value from a lagged variable and another external variable. I am aware that looping is not a good solution and that is why I was hoping someone has a better one. Avoiding concat inside the loop is a good point, I did that because I needed to access those calculated values in the next iteration, but I suppose I could access them also in a list of dataarray. About value assignment, I tried it but because the  `given_projection` and `da_forcalculation` have different dims order it didn't work.

Comment: I hear you. The assignment does work, though, you just have to do it correctly. If you want to take a stab at the assignment based version and then ask if you get stuck you can totally do that! But i I think the list or dict method is probably your best bet. If performance is a real problem you could use numba, but it’s a real challenge to get working